# merge 2 collections, prefer items of the second collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 collections of objects. the objects have an object-type 'key' property (I use object.ReferenceEquals to test the key). how do I merge collection A and B to produce a distinct collection C that has all the items of A and B but not those of A that have a matching key with an item in B?

**EDIT:** mind you, the collections might also be empty.

Comment: Do you care if, if two items in `B` have the same key, the second also gets discarded?

Comment: in this specific case B shouldn't ever have duplicate entries, if it did I guess just taking the first would suffice

Comment: OK. I was concerned because Union discards duplicates within each list as well as between the lists, but the added details in your question makes this less of an issue, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var toMergeA = A.Where(x => !B.ContainsKey(x.Key));
var C = toMergeA.Union(B);
```

Comment: I guess you mean 'var C = toMergeA.Union(B)', and I don't see an Except method with a lambda parameter on my collection's extension methods

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the principle is correct: C = A.Except(B).Union(B) and basically this is what I ended up using, other answers appear to be only variations on this principle

Comment: Where does the method `ContainsKey` come from? Are the collections dictionaries or just lists?

Answer (score 1):

This is also a possible solution:

```
var C = B.Concat(A.Where(a => !B.Any(b => a.Key == b.Key)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it returns a list of anonymous items.

```
public class X
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

List<X> xList = new List<X>();
xList.Add(new X() { Id = 0, Name = "a" });
xList.Add(new X() { Id = 1, Name = "b" });
xList.Add(new X() { Id = 2, Name = "c" });
xList.Add(new X() { Id = 3, Name = "d" });

List<Y> yList = new List<Y>();
yList.Add(new Y() { Id = 0, Age=20 });
yList.Add(new Y() { Id = 2, Age = 30 });
yList.Add(new Y() { Id = 4, Age = 40 });


var xQuery = from x in xList
             select new
             {
                 Id = x.Id                             
             };
var yQuery = from y in yList
             select new
             {
                  Id = y.Id

              };


        var un = xQuery.Except(yQuery).Union(yQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and wrote this extension method:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> left, 
  IEnumerable<T> right, 
  Func<T, T, T> resolveConflictFunc,
  IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
{
    equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    return left.Join(right, x => x, x => x, resolveConflictFunc, equalityComparer)
       .Union(left, equalityComparer)
       .Union(right, equalityComparer);    
}
```

Using the method, the solution is:

```
firstList.Merge(secondList,
                (left, right) => right) // conflict resolution function (takes the right one if exists in both)
```

In this case, the conflict is resolved by taking the item from the second collection.  The implementation allows you to inject more sophisticated conflict resolution logic.

The result is a combined distinct list.

I had some performance testing trying a hashset approach as well as a couple of LINQ approaches.  This implementation ended up being the fastest and simplest overall.